# How do I change color of text in the MDB navbar?

Tags: html, css, ms-access

It's a basic question but I can not find the answer anywhere and it is driving me crazy.

So in MDB you have the option to select .navbar-light or .navbar-dark, which sets the text to either black or white. I would like a softer gray but I have no idea how to change that. I tried to change the color in every .navbar-light class in the CSS sheet but I have only managed to change the color of the 'brand'.

Please help!

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet of your current navbar?

Answer (score 0):

Share your navbar code if possible. Try to change the color of nav-item .nav-link class.

```
.navbar.navbar-light .breadcrumb .nav-item .nav-link, .navbar.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link{color: grey;}
```

Comment: `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top yellow lighten-3">`

I tried chnging the color in every .navbar-light class and none had an effect, except for the brand name. I don't understand how that's possible (I am pretty new at this).